# How to change Number Picker min.max limit?

Tags: android, adapter, numberpicker

I am writing an custom number picker where range of picker should be change on other event.
I reset range using

```
pickerWeightRange.setMinValue(new_min_range);
pickerWeightRange.setMaxValue(max_new_range);
```

after then I checked with `pickerWeightRange.notify();` but it's same no change in limit.

Any suggestion to change limit @runtime.

It;s done, It was mistaken to handle switch statement...My Bad !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by debugging code.

Comment: That should happen automatically. Can you post some code about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Apoorv it's done, and it was my mistake mention in edited question. Can you tell me how to get index for selected row of picker!

Comment: Subtract the minimum value from the current value that will be your index. Why do you need that?

Comment: That will decide only range not selected value index, indexing using to fetch value from second list.